# Storing value to indexedDB if it is not defined

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, service-worker

I'm trying to check if there is a record of 'uid' in indexed db from a service worker. If it's not defined, I need to add a value to it.

This is my code, I already tried in some ways that I found around other questions and sites, but none worked.

```
function checkUid() {
  console.log('checking uid...');
  var request =  indexedDB.open('db',1);


  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore('Users', {keyPath:"users"});
    var transaction = event.target.transaction;

   db.transaction( '' ).objectStore( '' ).get( 'uid' ).onsuccess = 
    function(uid)
    {
        if (uid) {
          console.log('uid found!');
          console.log(uid);
          console.log('uid end');

        } else {
          console.log('not found!');
          db.transaction( '' ).objectStore( '' ).set( 'uid', 'aaaaa' );
          console.log('uid end');
        }
    }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The [`onsuccess`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest/onsuccess) callback gives an event as the first argument, not your 'uid'. You need `var request = db.transaction(…).objectStore(…).get(…)` and then `request.onsuccess = …` and inside the callback `var uid = request.result`.

Comment: @FredrikPortström not sure if I understand what you said. Can you give me an answer with the suggested code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code opens the database with the name `example`, creates the object store called `users` if needed, gets the object with the key `x123` from that store, and creates the object if it doesn't already exist.

```
function checkUid() {
  let openRequest = indexedDB.open("example")
  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = () => {
    console.log("update needed")
    openRequest.result.createObjectStore("users")
  }
  openRequest.onsuccess = () => {
    console.log("opened database")
    let store = openRequest.result.transaction("users", "readwrite").objectStore("users")
    let uid = "x123"
    let getRequest = store.get(uid)
    getRequest.onsuccess = () => {
      let result = getRequest.result
      if (result) {
        console.log("found:", result)
      } else {
        console.log("not found")
        store.add("aaaaa", uid)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm receiving this error: Uncaught TypeError: event.target.transaction is not a function
    at IDBOpenDBRequest.request.onsuccess

Comment: You're obviously not trying my code. I don't use `event.target`. I use `openRequest` instead. And it's `openRequest.result.transaction` or `event.target.result.transaction`, not `event.target.transaction`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to adapt to mine. My fault. It's working now.

Comment: One last doubt, how can I check if a uid record is defined? You are searching for a specific value, I just want to check if there is one defined otherwise I create one value.

Comment: In my example code, the object store stores records as key-value pairs, and I'm searching for a specific key (not a specific value), and I get the value associated with that key.

Comment: I'm getting this error on add: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses in-line keys and the key parameter was provided.

Comment: That's because this database structure uses key-value pairs. In your original code, you have a key path, but you also provide a key argument when you add the record. In my example I removed the key path. If you want to do it the other way, you can keep the key path and remove the key argument instead. For example `createObjectStore("users", {keyPath: "id"})` and then `store.add({id: "x123", name: "J. Doe"})`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143611/discussion-between-filipe-ferminiano-and-fredrik-portstrom).

Answer (score 1):

Use `put()` instead of `set()`, it will update the entry, or create one if it doesn't exist.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put